# Android Email Credentials location

Tags: android, email

Currently running Android version 6.0.1. I was wondering where in the file system username password is stored in the file system. I believe it has to obviously be stored locally as when you access Exchange setting of the Email App, the credentials are there but *'d out.

Long story short, I am trying to retrieve a password to an email account that is accessible for me through my phone but cannot remember my password. I'm aware it is likely encrypted. Any thoughts on location/retrieval? Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot access that area as it is protected called `root` you may want to contact the providers to set password. All the cache and package files are under root folder of the file system. Which not accessable to the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't.  Storing username and password is highly insecure.  Nobody competent does it.  Instead you receive an access token from the service, and use that in future requests to authenticate you.  That way at worst your session is stolen, not your account.

What you want can't be done, by design.

Comment: I see. I figured it should not be as easily accessible, although am not very familiar with authentication tokens and such. Thanks for the response and research topic.